# Yii2 Advanced - Extend View To Add Custom Variable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am not sure if what I am going for is the best Yii solution to handle this. So I am open to better solutions. Whatever is the most Yii way to do it.

I have a left sidebar that only needs to be shown to user's who are logged in. THAT is not the problem, I know how to show something by checking 'Yii::$app->user->isGuest'.

On specific pages, I do not want this sidebar, EVEN if they are logged in. For example, the 'Contact Us' page does not need to have the left sidebar on it. I really don't care if it does have the sidebar, but it is throwing off the Bootstrap3 columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 center-col">

        <div class="site-contact">
            <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

            <p>
                If you have business inquiries or other questions, please fill out the following form to contact us. Thank you.
            </p>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    [contact form code truncated]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

It looks great, centered in the middle of the page, 4 cols wide.

However, in my Yii main.php (frontend/views/layouts/main.php) I have 2 separate layouts, depending on if the user is logged in.

```
<div class="container-fluid mainpage">

    <?= Alert::widget() ?>

    <div class="row">

        <?php if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { ?>

            <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
                <?= Menu::widget([
                    'options' => ['class' => 'nav nav-sidebar'],
                    'items' => [
                            ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['site/index']],
                            ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['site/about']],
                            ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['site/contact']],
                        ],
                    ]);
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9">
                <?= $content ?>
            </div>

        <?php } else { ?>

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <?= $content ?>
            </div>

        <?php } ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

This code, shows a full width page if it's a guest, or a sidebar if the user is logged in.

What is happening on pages like the 'Contact Us' page, is the form gets scrunched because of the sidebar. The right content is 'col-md-9', and when you put the contact form into it (having 'col-lg-4') its only taking up 4 inside the 9 columns, resulting in it being scrunched.

Since this page (the contact page) should be publicly viewable (ie: if a user can't login, they would be screwed and not able to contact support), it is possible that both cases could happen. It may be viewed by a logged in member, resulting in the scrunched form, or by a guest that would look fine.

---

My approach was to add a variable $showSidebar. Then in contact.php have $showSidebar = false. The default action for the variable would be set by isGuest, and the pages could override it to turn off the sidebar on a per page basis.

I really don't want a ton of if checks for isGuest to show alternate div's or code, so I feel this would be the best approach.

**How do I extend the View to add my own variable?** The file is in vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/view I think..

This is the Yii2 advanced template.

**PS:** I am open to a better solution to my problem. I don't want hacks, but the most proper Yii way to do it.

Comment: I have solved it, though I am not sure it is the most Yii way to do it. To access the controller in Yii2 from your layout (main.php) or in the view pages (ie: contact.php) you use `$this->context->useSidebar`. Also put `public $useSidebar = true;` in your controller. I have it true as default because most of my pages will have the sidebar, only on special occasions I need it off. Then in contact.php, or in the Controller's action, set it to true/false.  -- Another option would be to have 2 layouts with/without sidebar, and in the view (contact.php) change the layout file.

Comment: PS: I didn't add my comment as an answer because it does not answer my question. I still would like to know how to extend the View class in Yii2 Advanced. I know how to extend a file, but where is it supposed to go? I know I could put it anywhere, but there has to be a common usage of where to put these extended classes for consistency among developers.

Comment: what is wrong with using 2 layouts, and in your controller action change the layout if you need to? The default layout can be the one with the sidebar, and on pages where you do not need the sidebar, you change the layout. But I know, this only solves half of your problems :)

Comment: Exactly :) As we all know, there are many routes that take us to the same destination. Many solutions are chincy hacks just to get the job done, and worry about the consequences later. I know the proper way, would be to extend the class and customize it as needed, and to not have many conditional if's scattered around deep in the code that we forget about later. I already set a variable in the controller "showSidebar", but it isn't the controllers job to delegate view behavior. -- So my question stil stands, how/where do I extend the view class?

Comment: I just found a project I am wokring on is also using a custom View. Check my answer - the view is a compoment so you can simply set it up to use a custom class of our own

Answer (score 4):

As the View is a Yii component, you can set it up like other components in the yii config file.
Just add sth like the following:

```
 'components'     => [
        'view'         => [
            'class' => 'app\components\extended\View',
        ],
```

Comment: Where do most people put the extended files? I noticed you put it in the "extended" directory. Also, the advanced setup doesn't have a components directory. I am looking for convention instead of just throwing them wherever I want that day.

Comment: Ok, let;s go step by step. Please tell me if that works for you, and then we look at where to place it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best solution is to create two layouts. One with the sidebar and another without the sidebar and use the desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution according to me is, create a database settings table which is mapped to user and organization and save the menu in that table for the specific user with respect to organization. So you can control menu according to per user specific to organization.

Also save a default menu in the settings which you can show to non logged in user(because that is default for everyone)